# Display popup after clicking on submit button in formidable form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, formidable

I am noobs in wordpress, I have created a form using formidable plugin.
I want to display popup message when click on submit button. I follow the following link

```
 https://timersys.com/how-to-display-a-popup-after-user-submits- 
 form/
```

but did not get success. Please help

Answer (score 3):

Follow these instructions mentioned in the Formidable form plugin docs. https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/javascript-examples/javascript-after-form-submit/#kb-before-redirect

They also give 2 different events that you can use to show your popup message if you want. 1) After success message, 2) After another page's content is shown

> Before redirect# You may use the frmBeforeFormRedirect event to run
>   custom code before a form is redirected to a new page. Please note
>   that this may only be used if 'Submit with AJAX' is selected in your
>   form's Settings. A basic example is shown below.

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).on( 'frmBeforeFormRedirect', function( event, form, response ) {
      var formID = $(form).find('input[name="form_id"]').val();
    });
  });
</script>
```

> The form object includes the form element that was submitted. The
>   response object includes the url that the page will redirect to. This
>   script may be placed in a form's Customize HTML.

Either replace the code `var formID = ...` with your popup message code or add it after that variable declaration if you need that variable for the popup message.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this but the requirement is different. Popup will display and user will close it by clicking on cross button, then user will be redirected to another page

Comment: Without actual code, I can't help you much but one possible solution could be that you use event.preventDefault(); to stop the event then show your popup and on close button click function you can submit your form manually.

Comment: I created a popup with popup builder plugin everything is fine. A Quick question is how to redirect on another page after cross image clicked on popup

Comment: You can do it with jQuery click event handler only. like jQuery('#selector').click(function() { location.href = 'http://www.techmuzz.com'; });